# Pig count query

Tags: apache-pig

I have to find out the number of students who scored less than 5.
 I have loaded the file.
I am using a  filter for grade< 5
I am not getting how to take the count now.
Can anyone please help

Comment: Can you post sample data and the script you have written? Have you looked at group by and count?

Comment: Thanks inquisitive mind

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#count)

```
A = LOAD 'student.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray,grade:int);
B = FILTER A by grade < 5;
C = GROUP B BY name;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE COUNT(B);
DUMP D;
```

Comment: @Jigyasa If this right answer then you have to accept answer.